# multivariate gaussian integral

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, integral

I am looking for the solution of multivariate gaussian integral over a vector x with an arbitrary vector a as upper limit and minus infinity as lower limit. The dimension of the vectors x and a are p $\times$ 1 and T is a symmetric positive definite variance-covariance matrix with dimensions p $\times$ p. See the integral below:

$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=a} x e^{ (-0.5 x'T^{-1}x)} d^p\bf{x}$$

I have tried to solve it with the cholesky decomposition and substitution with the Jacobian, but the dimension of the solution is not a p $\times$ 1 vector. When a equals $\infty$ the solution is of course an p $\times$ 1 vector of zero's (since it is the expected value).

Since I am not very experienced in integrating over vectors, also a good reference about this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What real life problem are you trying to model by imposing that upper limit. And is $T$ the covariance matrix?

Comment: For a good reference, consult any multivariate Calculus textbook.  To get a handle on what's going on, start with an explicit example with $p=2;$ say, $\mathbf{x}^\prime T^{-1} \mathbf{x}=x_1^2-2\rho x_1x_2+x_2^2$ for some $|\rho|\lt 1.$